# Matching opening and closing quote in JavaScript (simple quotes)

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to change all the simple quotes ("…") of a string to smart quotes (“…”):

```
str.replace(/"/g,'“');
```

But then I realized that, in order to do it, I have to match the opening and closing quote, something like this:

```
str.replace(/REGEX_FOR_OPENING_QUOTES/g,'“');
str.replace(/REGEX_FOR_CLOSING)_QUOTES/g,'”');
```

What regex should I use in this case?

Comment: Not sure why you would do that, but -> https://gist.github.com/zerolab/1633661

Comment: @adeneo: That answer doesn't have JS specific solution.

Comment: @anubhava - are you serious, I closed as a duplicate of this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202811/converting-straight-quotes-to-curly-quotes

Comment: Yes that answer says: **For languages that don't support look-behind, like Javascript, as long as you replace all the front-facing ones first, you have two options:** Question is how to get all **front-facing ones first**?

Comment: @anubhava - it's a javascript question with a javascript answer, actually 8 of them, where one is accepted. If you feel none of them answer the question, maybe you should close that one as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Yes that question is tagged as JavaScript but accepted answer doesn't have JS specific answer since it is using lookbehind which doesn't exist in JS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty naive approach which loops through every regular quote and toggles it between a smart open and close quote, but it may work for you...

```
function addSmartQuotes(str) {
  var open = false;
  return str.replace(/"/g, function(match, $1) {
    open = !open;
    return open ? '“' : '”';
  });
}

var str = 'This is my "string", blahdy "blah" blah';
console.log(addSmartQuotes(str)); // => This is my “string”, blahdy “blah” blah
```

It's also worth noting that unless you're sure that your page is in UTF-8, it's best to use HTML character codes for the open and closing quotes instead of the UTF-8 characters. These are `&ldquo;` (“) and `&rdquo;` (”).

Comment: `These are &ldquo; (“) and &rdquo; (”).` This is bad advice. HTML entities are not converted inside script tag. Use Unicode escape instead `\u201c` for the left quote, `\u201d` for the right quote.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, if you need to make sure that `"` forms a pair and you assume that two nearest double quotes should be matched:

```
input.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”");
```

Example run:

```
'"test" dskfjsdfklds "sdfsdf" "'.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”");
```

Output:

```
“test” dskfjsdfklds “sdfsdf” "
```

(The last `"` is not converted, since it does not form a pair)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead based regex:

```
var s = 'abc "quoted string" foo bar "another quoted text" baz';
var r = s.replace(/"(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)/g, '<').replace(/"/g, '>');
//=> abc <quoted string> foo bar <another quoted text> baz
```

**PS:** Replace `<` and `>` by `“` and `”`.

Trick is to find `"` that is followed by **odd number of `"`** using this lookahead first: `(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)`. Then remaining closing `"` can be replaced by `”`.

Comment: not sure why everything was turned to the opening smart quote only. I did this `chapterString = chapterContent.replace(/"(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)/g, '“').replace(/"/g, '”')` and I got thing: `<p class=””>”What?” My date`

Comment: I will post a jsfiddle demo link in few minutes after reaching back to my computer.

Comment: Oh yes I realized that it's because I have stuff like this `<p class="">"What?` and the code thinks it's a word. Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: @alexchenco: I don't know why you are accepting this monstrous regex as accepted answer, while there is a simpler solution using replacement function below.

Comment: @nhahtdh OK, I unchecked the answer. I'll wait for a while and see.

Comment: Monstrous regex really? This is fairly widely used regex pattern to detect even/odd # of quotes using pure regex solutions.

Comment: @anubhava: It is "widely" used, but I don't think many people can read and understand such code, compared to the solution with replacement function.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to read for programmers familiar with lookahead. `replace` with callback function will also make it possible but that is not pure regex solution. It can also be done by using a simple loop for that matter.

Comment: @anubhava: There is no need for a pure regex solution when the OP is using a programming language. The replacement function works well in this case without writing an explicit loop. These advanced regex should be reserved for when there is no other choice but a pure regex solution.

Comment: It is just a matter of choice, I guess, many regex can be replaced by alternative programming code actually. IMHO a simple loop that reads input chat by char makes it most readable.

Comment: @anubhava: See my answer for an alternate solution.