# String replace Double quotes into curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, ecmascript-6

How to replace all the Double quotes into both open and close curly brackets.

```
let str = "This" is my "new" key "string";
```

I tried with this regex

```
str.replace(/"/,'{').replace(/"/,'}')
```

But I end up with this:

```
{This} is my "new" key "string"
```

Here am getting only the first word is changing but i would like to change all the words.
I want the result to be:

```
{This} is my {new} key {string}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I kind of agree with whoever voted to reopen this question. While [the question about smart quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202811/converting-straight-quotes-to-curly-quotes) is quite similar, someone looking for a simple way to replace symmetrical delimiters with balanced pairs would need to scroll quite far down to find [the only answer that doesn't assume the input is English prose text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300917) there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using a global regex and use capture groups:

```js
let str = '"This" is my "new" key "string"';
str = str.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '{$1}');
console.log(str);
```

The `"([^"]*)"` regex captures a `"`, followed by 0 or more things that aren't another `"`, and a closing `"`. The replacement uses `$1` as a reference for the things that were wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Your code currently is only working for the first occurrence of each `{` and `}`. The easiest way to fix this would be to loop while there is still a `"` in `str`:

```js
let str = '"This" is my "new" key "string"';
while (str.includes('"')) {
  str = str.replace(/"/,'{').replace(/"/,'}');
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
str.replace(/\"(.*?)\"/g, "{$1}")
```

we need to use `g-gobal flag`. Here capturing string between double quotes "", then replace with matched string curly braces

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do that is to iterate over string as an array and every time it encounters character `"` replace it either by `{` or by `}` repeatedly.

```js
let str = '"This" is my "new" key "string"';
let strArray = str.split("");
let open = true;
for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; ++i) {
    if (strArray[i] == '"') {
        if (open === true) {
            strArray[i] = '{';
        }
        else {
           strArray[i] = '}';
        }
        open = (open == true) ? false : true;
    }
}
str = strArray.join("");
console.log(str)
```