# How do I let user input curly quotes rather than straight ones by JavaScript in a textarea/input[type=text]?

Tags: javascript, quotes

I found that in Google slides, when I type quotes, it will automatically displayed as curly `“”` ones rather than staright ones `""`.

Can I do the same thing with my `textarea` or `input[type=text]`? What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ″Straight Quotes″ to “Curly Quotes”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202811/converting-straight-quotes-to-curly-quotes)

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do I have to execute that replace function for every key up event?