# PHP Pretty Quotes

Tags: php

What's the best way to get PHP to convert regular quotes to pretty quotes.

i.e., convert -

straight quotes:

`Poe's Great Aunt Sally said Poe said, "Once upon a midday dreary."`

converted to curly "pretty quotes":

`Poe’s Great Aunt Sally said Poe said, “Once upon a midday dreary.”`

Comment: See [
Ideas for converting straight quotes to curly quotes
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509685/ideas-for-converting-straight-quotes-to-curly-quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
function convert_quotes($string) {
    $string = " " . $string . " "; //add spaces to beginning and end of string to catch strings that begin and/or end with quotes
    $search = array(" '", //use spaces to determine which direction a quote show curl.
                     "' ",
                     "'",
                     ' "',
                     '" '
    );
    $replace = array("&#8216;",
                    "&#8217;",
                    "&#8217;",
                    "&#8220;", 
                    "&#8221;"
    );

    return trim(str_replace($search, $replace, $string)); //replace quotes and trim spaces added at beginning of function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a plugin called "[SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)," originally created by John Gruber of Daring Fireball fame. It was originally created for MoveableType

But others have already created PHP versions that you can use. Check out this one:

http://michelf.com/projects/php-smartypants/

Or you can just run a Google search for "SmartyPants PHP" and you'll find more options.

Also for reference, people also refer to these as "smart quotes."

Comment: speaking of SmartyPants, I have a question on how to get post/get fields to convert to curly quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391924/smartypants-php-not-working-for-strings-submitted-by-post-get